# Connect to local web service (running under MAMP) from iPhone via WIFI.

Tags: ios, localhost, mamp, restkit

I have setup a local REST webservice  with MAMP.

I have setup a virtual host with the url "http://aem.davidcasillas" pointing to my public folder.

MAMP is listening on port 80.

If I access via Safari to "http://aem.davidcasillas/webservice/rest/getEventosToday" I get the correct json data.

Now I'm trying to access this web service from my iPhone application. I run it from XCode into the device.

The device is connected to my local network via WIFI, and the connection is working (I can   load webpages in safari)

I'm using RestKit to download the data and I'm trying to reach it with the same url I use in my Mac:  "http://aem.davidcasillas.es/webservice/rest/getEventosToday".

In the device I get the error:

```
NSURLErrorDomain -1003 Found no server for the specified host name.
```

How should I write my url so I can reach the web service from the iPhone?

NOTE: I have read this post: [test local websites with mamp on iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063119/test-local-websites-with-mamp-on-iphone) but none of this problems apply to my case. I have firewall disabled and my config.ini file shows the following listen line:

```
Listen 80
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround.

I use the WIFI ip address in SystemPreferences->NetWork in my Mac and then the whole path to the resource, so instead of:

```
"http://aem.davidcasillas.es/webservice/rest/getEventosToday"
```

I am writing:

```
"http://192.168.1.6/aem.davidcasillas.es/public/webservice/rest/getEventosToday"
```

The `192.168.1.6`part takes me to my local installation root folder `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/`.

In the rest of the path I have to put the whole path to the resource. Notice that I have to include the public folder in the path. Hope I could use my virtual host setup, but have not found a way.

Answer (score 1):

When I run `hostname`, it prints out

```
> hostname
ddopson.local
```

You can edit this in `System Preferences` ==> `Sharing` ==> `Computer Name`(text box at the top).  Note that in the "computer name" textbox, I filled in "ddopson".

If you are on WiFi, you should be able to connect to that hostname (ddopson.local) from your iPhone.  This works because both iOS and your Mac support [Multicast DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) where a multi-cast UDP packet is emitted onto the L2 network to lookup local hostnames.  When your Mac hears this multi-cast packet, it will reply to your iPhone with its ip-address and off you go.